# Result method called 3 times upon page call

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

I use simple method to view page, but upon using it I see that ok() method is called 3 times no matter what.

```
@Security.Authenticated(Secure.class)
public static Result index() throws SQLException {
    if (request().username() != null) {
        Logger.info("Main page called");
        return ok(main_page.render(User.getUserFromLogin(request().username()), Play.application().configuration().getInt("app.maxgameaccounts")));
    }
    return redirect(routes.MainController.login());
}
```

As you see logger is triggered 3 times each time I call method. Why is that?